# Iterate through list of objects in Python

Tags: python, list, class

```
     class Book:
     """Represents information about books.

     attributes: name, author, price, sold_units
     """
         def __init__(self):
             self.name : str = ""
             self.author : str = ""
             self.price : float = 0.0
             self.sold_units : int= 0
        
    def best_book(books : List[Book]) -> str:
    """Returns the name of the book that has sold more units.
    """
       result = ""
       ......
       return result

       titles = ['Think and Grow Rich', 'The Da Vinci Code', 'The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe']
    authors = ['Napoleon Hill', 'Dan Brown', 'C.S. Lewis']
    prices = [5, 5, 5]
    sold_units_per_book = [10, 20, 30]

    books = []

    for i in range(10):
        book = Book()
        book.name = titles[i]
        book.author = authors[i]
        book.price = prices[i]
        book.sold_units = sold_units_per_book[i]
        books.append(book)

    best_book(books)
```

I have the list of objects - books, and I need to return in my function best_book the name of the book that has sold more units.

I do't know how I can go through a list of objects using a foor loop, and find max value and at the same time return the name of the book.
Maybe something like this:

```
    for obj in books:
        max(obj.price)
```

Maybe someone knows how to do it?

Comment: `max(books, key=lambda b: b.price)`…

Comment: The question is asking for "the name of the book that has sold more units", not the highest price. So: `result = max(books, key=lambda book: book.sold_units).name`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated (if the best book is the one, that brought the most money):

```
def best_book(books : List[Book]) -> str:
   return max(books, key=lambda b: b.price * b.sold_units).name
```

Comment: max function already takes an iterable as argument, there is no need for the list comprehension as books is already an iterable.

Comment: But it gives such an error: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'